# TypeError: bar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'height'

Tags: python, python-2.7, bar-chart

I tried to recreate one of my excel chart using python but continuously hitting now a wall:

Here is the code as far as I managed to go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange

myfile = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Work In Prog\Alpha Data.csv', 'r')

label = [] # this is a string of the label
data = []  #this is some integer, some are the same value

for lines in myfile:

    x = lines.split(',')
    label.append(x[1])
    data.append(x[4])

dataMin = float(min(data))
dataMax = float(max(data))

pos = arange(dataMin, dataMax, 1)

p1 = plt.bar(pos, data, color='red', height=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar` expects the following:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)
```

You're doing:

```
p1 = plt.bar(pos, data, color='red', height=1)
```

Since you're (wrongly) passing `data` as second positional argument, when you pass `height` as named argument it is already passed.

Quickfix:

```
p1 = plt.bar(pos, 1, color='red', data=data)
```

(I admit I didn't check if your data was compliant)

Comment: Amazing! You saved my day with this.

Comment: I was half way there, in the right order just still treating it as a keyword argument, had to change it to a regular argument, so, from `width=width` to `width`